# Cannot install NPM package globally via Github branch

Tags: node.js, git, github, npm

The problem is that if I use a command like so:

```
npm install -g github:user/repo#branch_x
```

It will not install the latest package represented by that branch_x. I currently am guessing that it just uses the master branch. But I would like to install based off of a branch other than master.

I just opened this issue with NPM

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17623

Has anyone seen the same issue? Anyone know a workaround?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `npm install -g git://github.com/user/repo#branch_x`? Does that make a difference?

Comment: I can try that, but I think the docs say that the example I use above should work